# ImageMagick Append Large Files Using Stream Command

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

We need to append two very large TIF files vertically using ImageMagick, but we are very limited on memory and disk resources because we are attempting to do this on AWS Lambda.

We currently use the very simply approach here...

```
magick convert image1.tif image2.tif -append result.tif
```

This works, but because of the size of each image, the memory and disk consumption is too high and we run into resource issues.

ImageMagick has a "stream" command (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/stream.php) but I cannot find any examples of how we might use it for what we are attempting to do.

We have tried other approaches, such a the -limit option, but we still run into issues. I am trying to determine how this could be done using the "stream" command, if it is possible at all. I have seen "stream" suggested for this use case, but no examples.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at a machine to test, but I suspect you can achieve that using much less memory, and time, with [`vips`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/).

I think you'd want this at the command line:

```
vips join input1.tif input2.tif result.tif vertical
```

Add a final parameter of `--vips-leak` to check total memory used.

The `join` operation is documented here:

http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-join

There are node, PHP, Python, Ruby etc. bindings as well.

---

I created two 10,000x10,000 pixels TIF files and did the same append operation with ImageMagick and vips:

```
ImageMagick: 11 seconds and 4.86GB memory used
vips:         4 seconds and 157 MB memory used
```